# 2014 iMac Dual Boot error

Tags: dual-boot

I have inherited an old 2014 iMac and have tried dual-boot installing Ubuntu (20.04). I set up rEFInd and created a 200GB partition in MacOS for the install and followed the 'something else' option during install, rather than erase the disk completely.

The install went well. So well that the machine automatically boots in to Ubuntu. I don't seem to have an option to boot in to MacOS anymore. The 800GB APFS partition is still there. Is there a way to re-setup a boot selector?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Does Ubuntu detect MacOS when you run `sudo update-grub` and reboot? Also, which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: if it doesn't detect MacOS, you may have to enable os-prober in grub config. For that follow the answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373194/os-prober-and-update-grub-find-windows-install-yet-it-does-not-show-in-boot-men

Comment: Version 20.04.02. No change after 'update-grub' @ArchismanPanigrahi

Comment: @Esther no luck, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

When it installs, Ubuntu will, by default, install the GRUB 2 boot loader. When you boot, GRUB 2 will boot first, but it might or might not display a menu, depending on its settings and whether or not it's detected macOS. I haven't checked in quite a while, but the last time I did, Ubuntu's GRUB setup scripts did a poor job of detecting macOS. Thus, the system is probably booting to GRUB, which then goes straight to Ubuntu. If you're seeing either a GRUB menu or the rEFInd screen, then this is not right, and the below might not apply; please clarify what you see when the computer boots. If it's really showing no boot menu, though....

The easiest solution is to install rEFInd from within Ubuntu. You can do this by typing `sudo apt install refind` at a Bash prompt; that will install the version of rEFInd that comes with your Ubuntu distribution. To keep up-to-date with the very latest version, though, you can install the [rEFInd PPA](https://rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html#ppa) to get the latest version. After you install rEFInd in this way, it should appear when you reboot or start the computer "cold," and it should present options for both macOS and Ubuntu. The reason the installation you did from macOS isn't working is because GRUB 2 took over as the primary boot program once you installed Ubuntu. When using a non-standard boot manager like rEFInd, it must normally be installed *after* installing *all* the OSes on the computer.

Note that the rEFInd installed from Ubuntu will almost certainly replace the one installed from macOS -- it'll overwrite the files (keeping a backup of the original installation's configuration file and icons). Thus, you don't need to track down and uninstall the version you installed earlier.