# Windows not showing in BIOS after Ubuntu install

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have 4 drives, a 2TB HDD for data, a 1TB NVMe, a 240GB SSD with only Ubuntu 22.04, and a 240GB SSD with only Windows 10. I went to reinstall Ubuntu so I checked which drive was which, Ubuntu was on sda, and Winndows on sdb, so I installed Ubuntu formatting sda only. After installation, Ubuntu boots in correctly, but now it won't show the option for choosing where to boot. I checked the BIOS in case it removed the Windows boot option, but there was no option to boot into Windows, where just before re installing Ubuntu there was. I also checked to see if all the drives where being detected, and they are. I can also access the Windows drive through Ubuntu, I just can't boot into Windows.

Already tried`boot-repair` and it didn't work

Also tried `sudo update-grub` and also nothing.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Does this work? `sudo echo GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false >> /etc/default/grub && sudo update-grub`? ([Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1378891/124466))

Comment: It gives bash: /etc/default/grub: Permission denied

Comment: Ok, can you add the line `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` to `/etc/default/grub` using a text editor as root?

Comment: Did it, but didn't work. I also tried using a usb with the Windows 10 ISO to try reinstall Windows, but it won't let me boot into the usb

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in legacy mode by any chance? Windows 10 is probably running in UEFI mode. If Ubuntu is in legacy mode it will not see Windows. If so the solution is to reinstall Ubuntu in UEFI mode

Comment: Does Grub show up when you switch on the computer? Or does it go right into Ubuntu?